# Calling pipeline variables in yaml file(Repos)

Tags: azure-devops

I have the below situation:
In Azure Repos, i need to put and yaml file in which OAuth credentials needs to be placed and that yaml file is called while publishing the PowerShell script in release pipeline tasks.
My problem here is, i need to mask the OAuth which im providing under Repos yaml file as a plain text, when im trying to keep those credentials in pipeline variables and referring them in yaml file through $(OAuth) is not working.
Is it even possible to mask the OAuth in yaml file under Repos using pipeline variables? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> when im trying to keep those credentials in pipeline variables and referring them in yaml file through $(OAuth) is not working.

Secret pipeline variables cannot be referenced directly with `$(OAuth)` in PowerShell.

Here is an example about using a secert pipeline variable called `mySecret` in PowerShell. **Unlike a normal pipeline variable, there's no environment variable called MYSECRET.** Click [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) to get more detailed information.

> ```
> variables:
>  GLOBAL_MYSECRET: $(mySecret) # this will not work because the secret variable needs to be mapped as env
>  GLOBAL_MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(nonSecretVariable) # this works because it's not a secret.
>
> steps:
>
> - powershell: |
>     Write-Host "Using an input-macro works: $(mySecret)"
>     Write-Host "Using the env var directly does not work: $env:MYSECRET"
>     Write-Host "Using a global secret var mapped in the pipeline does not work either: $env:GLOBAL_MYSECRET"
>     Write-Host "Using a global non-secret var mapped in the pipeline works: $env:GLOBAL_MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR" 
>     Write-Host "Using the mapped env var for this task works and is recommended: $env:MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"
>   env:
>     MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(mySecret) # the recommended way to map to an env variable
> ```
>
> The output from the task in the preceding script would look like this:
>
> ```
> Using an input-macro works: ***
> Using the env var directly does not work:
> Using a global secret var mapped in the pipeline does not work either:
> Using a global non-secret var mapped in the pipeline works: foo
> Using the mapped env var for this task works and is recommended: ***
> ```